# customizing arraylist display in display tag

Tags: java, arraylist, displaytag

How can I customize the way showing arraylist in display tag when there is no data in array list? 
I just want to avoid displaying [] like this when there is no data.

Comment: (mylist.size() > 0 ? mylist.toString() : "")

Comment: is there any way that I can use ArrayList<String> instead of String as the bean has only that property? and if I use String, I need to add comma , between the multiple data for a particular item manually. Example: Employee can have multiple skills. And from diplaytag,I directly call the bean property which is ArrayList<String>.

Answer (score 0):

Use the help of tags on the client side, after getting request from the sever
Like `JST` tags or `STRUTS` tags:
Just check if the arraysize of your array is zero display empty ""
If it is not empty display content